# CSS: parent div doesn't resize when its insides do

Tags: css

I've got a simple CSS:

```
div.header
{
    width:auto;
}

div.footer
{
    clear:both;
}

div.middle
{
    margin:5px 0 5px 0;
}

div.links
{ 
    width:200px; 
    float:left;
}

div.content
{ 
    width: 900px;
    margin-left:210px;
}
```

and a simple page:

```
    <div class="header">
       <!-- some control inside -->
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
       <!-- left navigation list -->
       <div class="links">
           <!-- some control inside -->
       </div>
       <!-- content place -->
       <div class="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="myContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
       <!-- some control inside -->
    </div>
```

The control placed inside "links" div is sometimes resized by javascript. The control is resized, but the parent div ("links" div) isn't - it preserves its original height. As a result the footer doesn't move down and the control overlaps it. How can I fix this so that resizing this control will cause resizing the parent div and as a result moving the footer down?

Comment: Is this specific to any browser? I tried the same sample it works fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

When putting content into a div with a `float` property, I always place a div with `clear:both` at the end of its contents to ensure proper resizing. You already have a class `footer` which does this, if that's all it's for then use it here., e.g.:

```
   <div class="links">
       <!-- some control inside -->
       <div class="footer"></div>
   </div>
```

If you plan on having more style on `footer` you might want to create a new class just for this purpose.

Comment: i tried placing a div with clear:both in the links div just after the control - it doesn't work

Comment: and a footer is a footer - a panel at the bottom of a page - it's not some invisible div for resizing purposes

Comment: @agnieszka: Re-read the last sentence in my answer, you seem to have missed it.

Comment: I disagree with always placing a clear for floated elements. This will not always provide the desired effect depending on the design. There is a reason why floated elements are never contained by their parent.

Comment: @Rob: So mysterious!  Can you fill in the blanks?  E.g., this will not provide the desired effect when *X*.  The reason floated elements are never contained by their parent is *Y*.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I can't directly answer his question because his sample markup doesn't show the generated html.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two ways you can solve this:

1. overflow on `.middle`:

   ```
   .middle {
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```
2. put your footer (or another div with `clear:both`) inside middle, after the other two divs

Answer (score 2):

http://websticky.blogspot.com/2009/10/float-left-doesnt-expand-parent-div.html

heres an article about floating divs not expanding their parent divs

Comment: I don't understand why this is such a big mystery for some people, including the author in that link. The CSS docs are very clear about this: parent elements NEVER expand to contain floated elements. While IE used to do this, it was an incorrect implementation in the browser (among billions of others) that was corrected in IE8.

Comment: @Rob : thanks for pointing this out clearly. Parent elements NEVER expand to contain floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the height of the footer div and then subtract the re-size of the links div and set the difference as the new height of that footer div. In jquery, that might be something like:

```
$("#links").click(function() {

     var footer-height = $("#footer").css("height");
     var links-height = $("#links").css("height");
     var links_resize = ...code to determine how much to resize links div ....

     $("#footer").css("height, " footer-height - links_resize);

     $("#links").css("height, " links-height + links_resize);

});
```

Comment: i would rather do it without use of javascript - just construct css the way that would make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'float:left' to the parent div and see if that fixes it. Floated parents will contain floated children but parents are NEVER to expand just to contain floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe IE8 was supposed to fix this issue, but it isn't fixed. 
Take the code from that article for example

```
<style>
.container
{
   width:300px;
   background-color:green;
}
.box
{
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:3px solid red;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Try it in IE8. You get the same result with IE 5 - 7. According to the article, you also get it in opera. The only mystery here is why IE continuously disregards the css docs. Instead of floating the container left to fix it, either create an empty div after the floats and do clear:both; or as the article states, do overflow:hidden; (or auto)